# akka custom fork-join-executor dispatcher behaves differently on OSX and RHEL

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

When I deploy a Play framework application, using the Akka framework to a production machine it behaves differently then on my development workstation.

This is a system that receives a batch of device IP addresses, it performs some processing on each device and aggregates the results after all devices in the batch have been processed.  This processing isn't very CPU intensive.

I basically have 2 types of actors, A BatchActor, and a DeviceActor.  For the devices, I've created a created an actor backed by a RoundRobinPool router, and a custom dispatcher.  I'm attempting to process ~500 device at a time (in parallel).

This issue is that when I run this code on my OSX machine, it runs as I would except.

For instance if I submit a batch of 200 device IP addresses, the application running on my workstations all the devices in parallel.

However when I copy this application to the production machine, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), and run it submitting the same list of devices, **it only processes 1 to 2 devices at a time**.

What do I need to do to fix this issue?

The relevant code is as follows:

```
object Application extends Controller {
    ...

    val numberOfWorkers = 500
    val workers = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[DeviceActor]
          .withRouter(RoundRobinPool(nrOfInstances = numberOfWorkers))
          .withDispatcher("my-dispatcher")
    )

    def batchActor(config:BatchConfig) 
        = Akka.system.actorOf(BatchActor.props(workers, config), s"batch-${config.batchId}")

    ...

    def batch = Action(parse.json) { request =>
        request.body.validate[BatchConfig] match {

            case config:BatchConfig => {
                ...

                val batch = batchActor(config)
                batch ! BatchActorProtocol.Start

                Ok(Json.toJson(status))
            }

            ...

        }
    }
```

The application.conf configuration section looks like the following:

```
my-dispatcher {
  # Dispatcher is the name of the event-based dispatcher
  type = Dispatcher
  # What kind of ExecutionService to use
  executor = "fork-join-executor"
  # Configuration for the fork join pool
  fork-join-executor {
    # Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-min = 1000
    # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
    parallelism-factor = 100.0
    # Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-max = 5000
  }
  # Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be
  # processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.
  # Set to 1 for as fair as possible.
  throughput = 500
}
```

Inside the BatchActor I'm simply parsing the list of devices and feeding it to the

```
class BatchActor(val workers:ActorRef, val config:BatchConfig) extends Actor
  ...

  def receive = {
      case Start => start
      ...
  }

  private def start = {
      ...

      devices.map { devices =>
        results(devices.host) = None
        workers ! DeviceWork(self, config, devices, steps) 
      }

      ...
  }
```

after which the WorkerActor submits a result object back to the BatchActer.

My workstation: OS X - v10.9.3

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

production machine: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.1.2.el6_5-x86_64 u65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Software:

```
Scala: v2.11.2
SBT: v0.13.6
Play: v2.3.5
Akka: v2.3.4
```

I'm using typesafe activator/sbt to start the application.  The command is as follows:

```
cd <project dir>
./activator run -Dhttp.port=6600
```

Any help appreciated.  I've been stuck on this issue for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours spent trying different things including:

- doing research on different threading implementations on linux - pthreads vs NPTL
- reading through all the VM documentation on threading
- ulimits
- trying various changes in the Play and Akka framework configurations
- and finally a complete re-write of the thread management using scala futures, etc..

Nothing seemed to work.  Then I did a detailed comparison and the only thing that was different was that I used the Oracle Hotspot implementation on my laptop, and the OpenJDK implementation on the production machine.

So I installed the Oracle VM on the production machine and that seemed to fix the issue.  Even though I couldn't determine what the ultimate solution was, it seems that the default installation of OpenJDK on RHEL is complied or configured differently enough to not allow spawning of ~ 500 threads at a time.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but after ~ 3 days of searching I couldn't find it.

Comment: As I said in my comment below - its not clear why you need to spawn 500 threads at the same time. The default dispatcher only creates max. of 64 at the same time on a FJP.

Comment: The main reason is that I'm attempting to connect to as many devices as I can at the same time.  This programs needs to connect to many thousands of devices.  And I was attempting to create an Akka RoundRobinRouter with the number of instances set to ~500, or one device connection per DeviceActor instance in the router.  When I did that and left the parallelism-* and throughput options configured to the default values or to slightly increased values it only connected to 1,2 or ~10 at a time, which is much to low for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This could be happening because some part of your actor's receive method is blocking. Creating a thread per actor is a *not* the solution to this issue. You need to ensure that you don't spend a lot of time in each actor's receive method and none of your actor's receive method have any *blocking* code in them.

Comment: Yes, I've ensured that I don't have any blocking code in the receive method.  As I attempted to describe above, the exact same program behaves differently running under the OpenJDK as opposed the Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have too much *parallelism* in your code i.e., you are creating too many threads in your dispatcher. How many cores do you have on your Redhat box ? I've never seen such high value used. A lot of threads in FJ pool may be resulting in a large number of context switches. Try just using the default dispatcher and see if that fixes your issue or not. You can also change the values of min and max parallelism to 2 or 3 times number of cores you have.

```
fork-join-executor {
    # Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-min = 1000
    # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
    parallelism-factor = 100.0
    # Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-max = 5000
  }
```

Another thing to try is to create an uber jar using (sbt-assembly) and then deploy that instead of using activator to deploy it.

Finally, you can look inside your JVMs using something like VisualJVM or Yourkit.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't seem to have any effect.  Not matter what I changed it didn't seem to have make a difference on the RHEL machine.

Comment: Did you try without any dispatcher setting (i.e., let it take the default dispatcher).

Comment: Yes that is what I started with.  I only moved onto using the custom dispatcher after I started attempting different configurations to help track down a solution.

Comment: That's strange. How many cores do you have on your REHL box ? Because default dispatcher is configured for max of only 64 threads. See - http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#Listing_of_the_Reference_Configuration

Comment: I did take your point, maybe parallelism-max set to 5000 is set to high, and I will play around with performance tuning.  I was just trying to see how many devices I could connect to at once, and not crash the server.  :-)

Comment: Yes, I've read through those doc many times over the last few days.  I found a work around for my issue that I posted for the question.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: 5000 threads in a dispatcher will certainly kill your performance. I'm not sure if you know this or not - you don't need 500 threads to support 500 actors. Good luck.